# How can I save a URL to disk when viewing page source?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, download, web, url

I'm accessing a website which has MP3 files in the source, which are played through the page. I want to save these MP3s to disk and I can do this by view-source, copy the URL to a new tab, then saving after the page loads and it starts playing the MP3.

But this is cumbersome... I wish I could simply right-click the the URL in the view-source and save it. Is this something I can do... or can I copy-paste this URL directly into another tool which will do the same thing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux/OS X, you can use curl to download your file.

```
curl -o http://fs.geronimo.thisisglobal.com/audio/73df66a7758f45c8b35f85624d7c6536.mp4
```

If you're on Windows with at least PowerShell 3.0, you can try:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile videofilename.mp4 -Uri http://fs.geronimo.thisisglobal.com/audio/73df66a7758f45c8b35f85624d7c6536.mp4
```

Otherwise, you can just use your browser developer inspector to make a hyperlink with the file URI as its href attribute. For example, given [this link](http://fs.geronimo.thisisglobal.com/audio/73df66a7758f45c8b35f85624d7c6536.mp4), you can simply save the file by right clicking it and saving it as a file. To change the URL it's pointing to:

- Right click the link then choose "Inspect element".
- You should then be able to edit the **href** attribute to another MP4 link.
  [image]
- Repeat the process for all the links you need to download.

---

If you're doing this for a lot more pages/links, I suggest automating the process with JavaScript. I could help you with that, but that's a whole new different and it probably shouldn't be part of this answer.

Comment: Great to have several options, I shall give it a go (I might even have the Linux toolset on my Windows PC). If only they named the files in an obvious way I could properly automated it!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the audioUrl 'http://fs.geronimo.thisisglobal.com/audio/73df66a7758f45c8b35f85624d7c6536.mp4' into a new browser window. You may see a simple media player appear on the screen. Right click on the player and select 'Save As ...'.

Comment: This is in fact exactly what I do now. It works but is irritating as the MP3 starts playing. And the page in question also auto plays!